# Umbilical points on surface of revolution

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\sigma(u,v)$ denote a standard surface patch for a surface of revolution S with a given unit speed profile
curve $( f (u),0,g(u)), u$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$. That is, we consider the regular surface patch:
$\sigma(u,v) = ( f (u)\cos(v), f (u) \sin(v), g(u) )$  where $(u,v) \in \mathbb{R} \times ]-\pi, \pi[$ and $\dot{f}^2 + \dot{g}^2 = 1$

Find a function $f (u)$ such that every point on the (punctured) circle $\sigma(0,v)$, $v \in]-\pi,\pi[$, is an umbilical
point on S with identical (nonzero) principal curvatures $\kappa _1 (0,v) = \kappa _2(0,v)$ and such that S does
not contain any other umbilical points. Use your function f (u) to produce a drawing of the surface.

Answer (score 1):

Fritz: Here's one way to come up with an example. In the $xz$-plane, start with a semicircle of radius $1$ (with center at the origin). Inscribe a parabola $C$ tangent to it at $(1,0)$ and with the same curvature: say $x=1-z^2/2$. Rotating a piece of this curve around the $z$-axis will give you such a surface $S$. (You can easily compute the curvature of the "profile curve" $C$, and you can compute the other principal curvature easily by applying Meusnier's formula. They will be equal only when $z=0$.)